# How do I send an embed message that contains multiple links parsed from a website to a webhook?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord, webhooks, discord.py

I want my embed message to look like this, but mine only returns one link.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

url = 'https://www.solebox.com/Footwear/Basketball/Lebron-X-JE-Icon-QS-variant.html'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
for tag in soup.find_all('a', class_="selectSize"):
    #There's multiple 'id' resulting in more than one link
    aid = tag.get('id')
    #There's also multiple sizes
    size = tag.get('data-size-us')
    #These are the links that need to be shown in the embed message
    product_links = "https://www.solebox.com/{0}".format(aid)

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='WebhookURL')
embed = DiscordEmbed(title='Title')
embed.set_author(name='Brand')
embed.set_thumbnail(url="Image")
embed.set_footer(text='Footer')
embed.set_timestamp()
embed.add_embed_field(name='Sizes', value='US{0}'.format(size))
embed.add_embed_field(name='Links', value='[Links]({0})'.format(product_links))
webhook.add_embed(embed)
webhook.execute()
```

Comment: Does `type(product_links)` say that it's a `List` or a `String`?  Glancing at it, it would appear that every iteration of `for tag in soup.find_all('a', class_="selectSize")` is just overwriting the previous value of `product_links`

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely get you the results you want.  `type(product_links)` is a string, meaning that every iteration in your for loop is just re-writing over the `product_links` variable with a new string.  If you declare a List before the loop and append `product_links` to that list, it will most likely result in what you wanted.

**Note**: I had to use a different URL from that site.  The one specified in the question was no longer available.  I also had to use a different header as the one the asker put up continuously fed me a 403 error.

**Additional Note**: The URLS that are returned via your code logic return links that lead to no where.  I feel that you'll need to work that one through since I don't know what you're exactly trying to do, however I feel that this answers the question of why you where only getting one link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.solebox.com/Footwear/Basketball/Air-Force-1-07-PRM-variant-2.html'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}

r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

product_links = [] # Create our product

for tag in soup.find_all('a', class_="selectSize"):
    #There's multiple 'id' resulting in more than one link
    aid = tag.get('id')
    #There's also multiple sizes
    size = tag.get('data-size-us')
    #These are the links that need to be shown in the embed message
    product_links.append("https://www.solebox.com/{0}".format(aid))
```